# Steps in creating custom frameworks

Tags: cocoa

How can I create custom frameworks in cocoa? Please tell me the steps to create a simple framework like it should contain addition of two number functions in its class.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation? The [Framework Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html) answers the general question (in other words, read the docs then ask more pointed questions).

If you're only adding methods to an existing class, however, just use [categories](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1).

Comment: Ya i have read and created one frame work, but when i tried to reuse in another application by importing the framework i am not able to use the method which contains in one of the framework class.

Comment: iSight: You need to ask a more specific question about the problem you're having.

Comment: I have created framework name Addition. It contains class called Add, which has methods called -(float)addFirstNumber:(float)first andSecondNumber:(float)second. I have imported that framework in my sample application to test. But, when i import Add.h as usually done inaccessing mentioned method, i could not access the header file, from the said framework.

Comment: iSight: You need to ask that in its own question (and provide much more detail in that question about the problem you're having).