# Steps to have a framework approved by Apple

Tags: ios

Say I have created a framework and want to publish it to github. In what circumstances will this framework be rejected by Apple / won't be allowed to publish to github...? Also, when will my framework be accepted by Apple..? Or is there any step as such at all...?

I have referred this (https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios) link and this ([Steps in creating custom frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591955/steps-in-creating-custom-frameworks)) also. Though the first one showed how to make a framework it didn't tell when a framework will be accepted or rejected. The second one also didn't help...

Comment: which kind of framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple doesn't approve or reject frameworks.  You can publish anything you want on GitHub.

Apple reviews apps.  People can use your framework in their apps if they like.  If your framework does something wrong (say, uses private API) then those people may get their app rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks are not published on App Store. So there is no point on its rejection.
Its Apps which can get rejected because of some framework. And people will stop using your framework, if apple rejects app because of something wrong in it.